# Am I missing something or this is the way to create custom control/component

Tags: qt, layout, qml, qqmlcomponent

In my `Card.qml`, I've these:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Item {
    default property alias content: x.children /*contentItem.data*/
    property alias header: header.text

    Rectangle{
        id: rect
        anchors.fill: parent
        ColumnLayout{
            anchors.fill: parent
            Text{
                id: header
                font.bold: true
                leftPadding: 10
                topPadding: 10
            }
            Rectangle{
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.leftMargin: 5
                Layout.rightMargin: 5
                height: 2
                border.color: "black"
            }
            Item {
                id: x
                Layout.margins: 10
                Layout.topMargin: 0
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }
        }
    }
    DropShadow{
        anchors.fill: rect
        source: rect
        radius: 10
        samples: 15
        color: "black"
    }
}
```

in `Field.qml` these:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Item {
    id: root
    property alias label: label.text
    property alias placeholder: field.placeholderText

    RowLayout{
        anchors.fill: root
        Label{
            id: label
            Layout.minimumWidth: 50
        }
        TextField{
            id: field
        }
    }
}
```

and in `main.qml` these:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: "Test Window"

    GridLayout{
        anchors.fill: parent
        columns: 2
        rows: 2
        Card{      
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.margins: 10
            header: "H1"
            Text{text: "text 1"}
        }
        Card{
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.margins: 10
            header: "H2"
            Text{text: "text 2"}
        }
        Card{
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.margins: 10
            header: "H3"
            Text{text: "text 3"}
        }
        Card{
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.margins: 10
            header: "H4"
            ColumnLayout{
                Field{
                    label: "Name"
                    placeholder: "name"
                }
                Field{
                    label: "Age"
                    placeholder: "age"
                }
                /*
                TextField{}
                TextField{}
                */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when I run the application it looks like this:

[image]

First problem is the last `Field` on the 4th `Card` is on top of first `Field`, why? Second, in every `Card` I've to have these for it to render properly:

```
Layout.fillHeight: true
Layout.fillWidth: true
Layout.margins: 10
```

I could put these 3 lines in `Card.qml` BUT in that case I probably would always have to use that in some `Layout`, right?

Third in `Card.qml`, in the 1st `Rectangle` although I've `anchors.fill: parent`, I again have to have `anchors.fill: parent` in the `ColumnLayout` inside that, why?

I couldn't find a `Separator` control in QML so I'd to use another `Rectangle` there with `height: 2`. I wanted to make that separating `Rectangle` thinner so I put `height: 1` and it doesn't even appear on the `Window` with `height: 1`!

Though I've already mentioned twice that `anchors.fill: parent` in root `Rectangle` and `ColumnLayout` inside it, I again have to have `Layout.fillWidth: true` in separating `Rectangle` and content `Item`.

Am I laying out things properly in QML or there's easier way to do?

Answer (score 0):

New definition of `Field`:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

RowLayout{
    property alias label: label.text
    property alias placeholder: field.placeholderText

    Label{
        id: label
        Layout.minimumWidth: 50
    }
    TextField{
        id: field
        Layout.fillWidth: true
    }
}
```

solves the overlapping issue and it actually makes sense: `Label` tells the `RowLayout` to give it at least 50 pt/px/whatever and the `TextField` orders it to allocate the remaining width.

I've brought these lines

```
Layout.fillHeight: true
Layout.fillWidth: true
Layout.margins: 10
```

in the `Card` definition:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Item {
    default property alias content: content.children /*content.data*/
    property alias header: header.text
    property double margin: 10
    property double separatorMargin: 5

    Layout.fillHeight: true
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    Layout.margins: 10

    Rectangle{
        id: rect
        anchors.fill: parent
        ColumnLayout{
            anchors.fill: parent
            Text{
                id: header
                font.bold: true
                leftPadding: margin
                topPadding: margin
                //Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop
            }
            Rectangle{
                id: separator
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.leftMargin: separatorMargin
                Layout.rightMargin: separatorMargin
                height: 2
                border.color: "black"
                //anchors.top: header.bottom
            }
            ColumnLayout {
                id: content
                Layout.leftMargin: margin
                Layout.rightMargin: margin
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                //anchors.top: separator.bottom
            }
        }
    }
    DropShadow{
        anchors.fill: rect
        source: rect
        radius: 10
        samples: 15
        color: "black"
    }
}
```

and I'm still lost in this. In the first `ColumnLayout`, the line `anchors.fill: parent` tells it to occupy the whole area of `rect`, right? AND isn't the second `ColumnLayout (id: content)` with `Layout.fillHeight: true` telling the `content` to fill the remaining height of the first `ColumnLayout`? Here's how it looks now:

[image]

Although I've `Layout.fillHeight: true` in `ColumnLayout (id: content)`, the root `ColumnLayout` doesn't care! It evenly distributes the whole space between `Text (header)`, `Rectangle (separator)` and `ColumnLayout (content)`, why? Am I still missing something?

Here's the content of `main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: "Test Window"

    GridLayout{
        anchors.fill: parent
        columns: 2
        rows: 2

        Card{
            header: "H1"
            Text{text: "text 1"}
        }
        Card{
            header: "H2"
            Text{text: "text 2"}
        }
        Card{
            header: "H3"
            RowLayout{
                Field{
                    label: "Name"
                    placeholder: "name"
                }
                Field{
                    label: "Age"
                    placeholder: "age"
                }
            }
        }
        Card{
            header: "H4"
            ColumnLayout{
                Field{
                    label: "Name"
                    placeholder: "name"
                }
                Field{
                    label: "Age"
                    placeholder: "age"
                }
                Field{
                    label: "Address"
                    placeholder: "address"
                }
                Field{
                    label: "Age"
                    placeholder: "age"
                }
                Field{
                    label: "Address"
                    placeholder: "address"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I've to give that `ColumnLayout (content)` an exact or much bigger height to solve the issue! this definition:

```
ColumnLayout {
    id: content
    Layout.preferredHeight: parent.height
    Layout.leftMargin: margin
    Layout.rightMargin: margin
    //Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop
}
```

let it occupy the available space. Problem now is the content inside it is vertically centered.

[image]

I've tried with two other container `Item` and `Flow` BUT none of those resize its content on Window size change.

Are `GridLayout`, `ColumLayOut` and `RowLayout` the only Layouts that respond to Window size change?

**EDIT**

`StackLayout` instead of `ColumnLayout` for `content` solves the problem!